# Can I replace will with shall in this sentence？

Tags: word-usage

I have watched the film They Shall Not Grow Old by Peter Jackson.
What does the subtle difference make if I change the name of this film into They Will Never Grow Old？

Comment: We use *shall* to make a stronger statement, one suited the heightened sensation of book and movie titles as well as somewhat overwrought dialogue. *Will* is more ordinary, more pedestrian, less oratorical. Cf. another Peter Jackson film, The Fellowship of the Ring, in which the wizard Gandalf strikes his staff on the stone floor and proclaims to the balrog "You ... shall not ... pass!" It just wouldn't be the same using *will*.

Comment: By the way, the title was taken from a 1914 poem (http://www.greatwar.co.uk/poems/laurence-binyon-for-the-fallen.htm) by Laurence Binyon. It is well known in the UK and gets recited each Remembrance Sunday. The fourth verse was chiselled into countless war memorials here. Headstones often had just the first line of the verse or, stonemasons charging what they do, the first **half** of the line, which is the title of the film.

Comment: @Robusto I would enjoy hearing Gandalf declaring "You maybe shouldn't oughta pass, ya know. I mean I'm just sayin' is all."  
Per the question; it would be improper to change *any* word of any title no matter what effect is desired. Otherwise Robusto is quite correct.